# How to send a message to Slack using curl from gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci, slack

I am using GitLab for a CI/CD process. I want to send messages to my channel in Slack. Following the API works from the terminal:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Hello, World!"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx/yyyy/zzzz
```

However, when I put this line into my .yml file, it gives me a "yaml invalid error". Complete block is here:

```yaml
slack_jar:
  stage: slack
  before_script:
    - echo "hi there"
  script:
    - curl -F file=@target/springApp-0.0.1.jar -F channels=#application_dev_backend -F token='xoxb-1111-2222-yyyyyy' https://slack.com/api/files.upload
  only:
    - dev
    
slack_message:
  stage: slack
  script:
    - echo "Send Slack Messages"
    - curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Hello, World!"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxx/yyyy/zzzz
  only:
    - dev
```

The first stage (sending file) is correct, but the second one is not working. This is the error message I get:

> Status: syntax is incorrect Error: jobs:slack_message:script config should be a string or an array of strings

Comment: As I remember, multiple `script` keys in a job is not allowed and there must be one `script` per job. Please remove the first one.

Comment: You're allowed having a `before_script`, `script` and `after_script`, so you're good there. Can you post the complete error message? Are you using gitlab CE or EE?

Answer (score 4):

Based on your error message, the curl command in `slack_message` is incorrect. Try wrapping the entire command in quotes and escaping the internal quotes. The way you have it, the YAML parser thinks the `Content-type: application/json` is a key:value pair of a dictionary.

Try this instead:

```yaml
slack_message:
  stage: slack
  script: 
    - echo "Send Slack Messages"
    - "curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{\"text\":\"Hello, World!\"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxx/yyyy/zzzz"
  only:
    - dev
```

#### Pro Tip

You can use the `CI Lint` tool to validate the contents of `gitlab-ci.yaml`. You can access this in the `CI/CD > Pipelines` screen. See [CI Lint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/lint.html).

There is also a useful website http://www.yamllint.com/ where you can input YAML, and it will (a) validate it, and (b) return a UTF-8 version. If you have string problems, the UTF-8 version will look mangled (which is what happens with your YAML).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. this is the error message I get. "Status: syntax is incorrect 

Error: jobs:slack_message:script config should be a string or an array of strings"
your know that I have 2 stages. one stage is for sending file and another stage is for sending text message to channel. the first stage (sending file) is correct but another one is not working

Comment: I have edited the main question body and I put two body blocks for slack, the first one is correct but second is not true and I am getting an error.

Answer (score 2):

Please give required privilege to bot User to post in channel.
follow the below ci.yaml

#please select the image which has curl command

```
slack_notification:
  image: ubuntu:latest
  script:
    - echo "Get user id with curl from Slack"
    - curl -X GET -H 'Authorization:Bearer <bot token>' https://slack.com/api/users.lookupByEmail?email=$GITLAB_USER_EMAIL | jq -r '.user.id'
    # From the above if you change the | jq -r '.user.name' then you will get the name of the user from slack.
    - echo "Slack post request"
    - >
      curl -X POST -H 'Authorization:Bearer <bot token>' -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"channel":"<channel id which start CXXXX>","text":"Your job has been finished please validate Job Url '"$CI_PIPELINE_URL"'"}' https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage
```

CI_PIPELINE_URL: This will give the job url.

Slack reference: https://api.slack.com/web